# Sound Quality: Does the choice of operating system or software affect quality of sound?

Tags: audio, kodi

Has anyone done a sound quality comparison between Audiophile and Media Centre operating systems?

On a simple Pi-for-stereo that uses only the onboard sound card, will I get better sound if I use Volumio/RuneAudio?  Do they use better drivers or output better sound without using an external digital-analogue-converter?  Will I get the same sound if I use Rasbian or Openelec with media centre software (Kodi)?

I like the simplicity and responsiveness of Volumio, but I think my wife would prefer browsing more easily with album art and such.

Comment: Well, go for the wife-accepted solution. It's the only way ;)

Comment: Or get into the spirit of [F.O.S.S.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software) and get something that does what *you* want it to do and meet the demands of the significant other - just don't let them become a *coding widow*...

Answer (score 1):

The verdict is in: Volumio does provide better sound even without an additional DAC.  My wife even agrees, so Wohoo!

It was a subjective comparison, no charts or anything.  We listened to a few tracks in Volumio and again in Openelec (Kodi).  The difference was unquestionable.  The difference was greater with lossless (flac) files than with high quality mp3 files.  That surprised me; I assumed any difference would be linear.

I'm still interested if anyone has any insight or alternatives.  If there's a way to enjoy higher sound with Kodi, then I'm all ears.  (Pun intended!)